# Menu items overlapping in ie8

Tags: html, css, menu

Hi – for some reason 2 of my menu items are overlapping in ie8 (see screenshot below – items “about us” and “press” and also background is white in the space between these 2 items) on my sitehttp://goo.gl/34oQ8 - Any idea why?

[image]

CSS Code

```
#nav
{
        right:2%;
        list-style:none;
        position:fixed;
        /* float:right; */
        top:30px;
        z-index:1000;
        /* width:520px; */
}

#nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* dirty hack for IE7 */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

#nav a
{
        font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-weight:600;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        float:left;
        top:30px;
        display:inline-block;
        font-size:11px;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-right:5px;
        padding-left:15px;
        padding-right:15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        height:24px;
        color:#666;
        line-height:24px;
        text-align:center;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        /* background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);  removed not ie8 compatible */
        text-transform:uppercase;
        background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: Alpha(opacity='80');
}

#nav a:hover
{
        background:#dedede;
}

#nav .current a
{
        background:#666;
        color:#ededed;
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <ul id="nav">
  <li class="current"><a href="#presentation">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#equipe">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#plan-activite">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#medias">Press</a></li>
  <li><a href="#inline" class="modalbox">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I remember this site, few days ago there was form issue :)

Comment: yes, I think this was fixed, but still having this issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think putting a margin on `<a>` elements will space out your `<li>`'s which is what you want. Try adding margin-left and/or margin-right to `nav li` instead

also, HTML5 includes a `<nav>` tag that would nicely replace your id="nav"

Comment: Thanks both, i'll try this. How come the issue only appears btw items "About us" and "Press" though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move ALL of your spacing and padding elements into the #nav > li .

The code in the #nav a should only be for styling that link item where as the LI can be used for styling the menu item itself.

```
#nav > li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 5px;
            padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

This would begin cleaning the code a bit..